# How can I customize the title bar on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, customization, jframe, titlebar

I would like to have a customized title bar in my Java Swing desktop application. What is the best way to do that? I can use a "Swing-title bar" by using the following code in the constructor for my JFrame:

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
this.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

But how do I customize it? Is there any **UI delegates** that I can override or do I have to implement my own title bar from scratch?

I want something like Lawson Smart Office: [image: Lawson Smart Office]

Comment: You know, I wish you wouldn't - I want all my windows to look consistent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see an example in [Substance look-and-feel](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/) ([mirrored source](https://github.com/kirillcool/substance)). Search the code for SubstanceRootPaneUI and SubstanceTitlePane. The implementation depends on other classes in Substance, and will not be easy to reuse outside the specific library - nor is it meant to.