# How do I go about putting a JButton in the chrome of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, firefox, jframe, jbutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize the title bar on JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781987/how-can-i-customize-the-title-bar-on-jframe)

Firefox 4 introduced a button that is flush to the edge of its frame. Opera has had such a button for some time, as has other software. Frame buttons such as this have the advantage of being hard against the screen edges when the window is maximised, which give them an infinite target size according to [Fitt's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts_law).

[image: Firefox 4 Frame Button]

Does anyone know of a component or library which will achieve the same thing in Swing? Or failing that, how to start go about implementing such a thing for myself. I'm thinking of maybe a JFrame without any frame decoration and dealing with implementing minimise, etc. myself with other JButtons. I think I'd much prefer for someone else to have solved this problem properly for me!