# Java nimbus Look and feel view is always different

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I have set the look and feel nimbus in my java application, but i dont know why the view is always different from one frame to other. in a frame I got perfectly good blue nimbus, and in other frame I got the grey one but that's not proper. and the other one was not displayed as using nimbus look and feel. here's the code that I use in main

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

I also import

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
```

I hope somebody can help me, thank you.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612592/jframe-and-nimbus-look-and-feel

Comment: Does it work correctly if you run the app with `java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel MyApp` (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)

Answer (score 5):

When you switch from one Look and feel to another, you must make sure to invoke the `SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI` method once for each top-level container. Also, if you store UI components which are not part of any visible UI/top-level container, you will have to update those as well.

For example if your second panel was already created when you switch look-and-feel, make sure to update it as well.

There is, like for almost anything in Swing, a rather good [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) available