# What are font properties of titlebar in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How to get the font properties of titlebar in JOptionPane. I am using linux OS system. We can get font properties of other java component using getFont API but as titlebar is OS dependent (native), what is the way to get font properties of titlebar ?

Comment: If supported, you might be able to leverage `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7612592/230513) for `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control titlebar decorations on Linux before Wayland, which is not generalized yet, and even in a Wayland world that will depend on the desktop environment, its toolkit, and how much leeway it gives to individual apps.

Probably a lost cause if you add the Java/native toolkit barrier. Java is not even using GTK3 yet, I doubt GTK2 will ever get more than minimal Wayland love and exploiting Wayland from GTK3 will probably require deeper support than just a minimal GTK2 glue replacement.

You may have more luck with SWT.

[OpenJDK GTK3 support](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145568)

Comment: I have gnome 2.28.2 installed. I am trying to install gnome-tweak-tool, but not able to install yet.