# Move position of javafx application stage title text

Tags: java, javafx

My JavaFX applications look even more different between Windows and OSX than I'd like, as the title text on the mac is centered, but on Windows its left aligned. Ideally I want to make both centered.
Compare OSX
[http://i.imgur.com/48YGy5D.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shbxt.png)
with Windows:
[http://i.imgur.com/alvWo2n.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPz9G.png)

Of course, I'd like to know if anyone has found a way to get around this default?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found is to make an undecorated window and add my own title bar to the top of the frame, this way I have full control over everything and the OS/platform will never interfere with the layout.

See here for more info on one way you could do this:
[How to create customize title bar with close button on jFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822037/how-to-create-customize-title-bar-with-close-button-on-jframe)

Comment: ok, shame the javafx people didn't give a us a way to do it, .but I guess it keeps it looking 'native'. The link is for swing but I guess the same approach will work. Thanks.