# Suggestions on using a Look and Feel for my Java project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, nimbus

I want to use a Look and Feel for my Java GUI project (in Swing) in which the **windows container's frame color is dark and the color of the body of the container is white.**

As an example, you can see the picture of the browser: the frame is black while the body is white. I want something like that in my Java GUI project. *Preferably* a `Nimbus L&F`, so **any suggestions?**

[image]

Comment: I have just been searching on whichever L&F to use. I haven't tried using one yet, since I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Have a look at the links shared by me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer. I have accepted that answer. But if you just downvoted, I am afraid I don't agree because I asked for suggestions on which L&F to use... so that was my search query before posting the question!

Comment: I haven't down voted your question but at least I can up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one for `Nimbus` look and feel.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to 
            // another look and feel.
        }
    }
});
```

---

For more info have a look at below links:

- [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#themes)
- [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)
- [How can I customize the title bar on JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781987/how-can-i-customize-the-title-bar-on-jframe)
- [JFrame TitleBar FAQ](http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/Swing/JFrame/TitleBar.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [**JTattoo**](http://www.jtattoo.net/) look and feel library, with an assortment you can choose from

Here are a couple from the library

**JTattoo Acryl LAF**

[image]

**JTattoo Graphite LAF**

[image]

Comment: Does it require license?

Comment: This looks exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!