# Swing: Add help [?] button to window titlebar

Tags: java, swing, titlebar

I want to add the new button with an icon of a question mark to the left of buttons "maximize", "hide" and "close". how to make it (like in a pic)?
[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Swing. Not sure about other toolkits, but I doubt it.

Comment: Welcome to what is probably amongst one of the most requested features for Swing. No, you can't do it. You "might" be able to use JNI/JNA solution, but that's a lot of work and you'd need to consider the need to provide cross platform support

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom RootPane/TitleBar.

This means you need to set your JFrame to undecorated and then set your custom instance of what extends RootPane to your JFrame

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to change native Title bar, because it is originating from the operating system. But you can remove native Title-bar `setUndecorated(true);` and create your own Title-bar , See simple tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT8gl6R2xmc)

OR

You can see an another way in [Substance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793051/4029284) look-and-feel