# Edit JFrame title bar color

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm building a Java Swing application and I'm trying to change the frame to look like this:
[image]

How do I achieve that?

I have tried to change the color of the JFrame title with no success :(

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Java SDK 8.

Comment: Did you check here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781987/how-can-i-customize-the-title-bar-on-jframe

Comment: @GökselÖZER This solution fits for SDK 9 and above...

Comment: You can remove the title bar and set the custom bar. First, set undecorated true from JFrame and add Panel top of the JFrame. Add buttons in the panel and set these are close, mini-maxi and hide. You can do with that way.