# How to remove minimize button and keep maximize and close button in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to remove only minimize button from JFrame 
but want maximize and close button in JFrame title bar.

Here I am talking about removing not disabling.

Comment: So instead of minimizing this abominable app. I need to close it completely?  It won't be opened again..  I suggest you stop stuffing with buttons the user expects to see on windows on *their* computer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think removing the minimize button is a good thing. But may be you can use the [setUndecorated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) method to remove the title bar and window edges. And you'll have to add your own close and maximize buttons to perfom those action.

Here is an example :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Example {

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);//<---- this will disable the frame decorations
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("titlebar"));
        //Add button maximize
        JButton button_max=new JButton("Maximize");
        button_max.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if(frame.getExtendedState() == JFrame.NORMAL) {
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                } else {
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_max);
        //Add button close
        JButton button_close = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Close") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4901571960357967734L;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button_close);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Example();
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

As @peeskillet states in the comment, even with this method the window still can be resized and draged by the user. The [ComponentResizer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/)  class allows to do that.

Here is a an SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476496/drag-and-resize-undecorated-jframe/24476755#24476755) which gives a good example to use this class with `Jframe`.

Comment: Also D&D support, system menu support, window resizing support, expansion on double click (OS depended) must be provided. So it will take some days (or probably weeks) to implement all the functionality of title bar.

Comment: That's true. With this method the user will not be able to resize the window.

Comment: @peeskillet great ! this will permit the user to resize and drag the obtained window. Thank you. I'll add an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**It's a very big hack, which works only with [Synthetica L&F](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/) because it provides a painted title bar. Note: this L&F is not free to use. So if you use it you must by a license.**

When you use this L&F you can iterate over all component starting from root pane to find an instance of `SyntheticaTitlePane`. On success you can try to access the field `iconifyAction` using [Reflection Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and use the method `Action.setEnabled(false)` on it.

I have no idea how to access the standard title bar because it's native. Probably it's impossible.