# Moving a JFrame with custom title bar

Tags: java, jframe, drag, mousemotionlistener

How can I move a `JFrame` having a custom title bar?

I remove the default title bar and I did my own design. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I want to know how to drag a `JFrame` when the cursor is placed on the title bar only and not the whole frame. I've searched already and I have seen a lot of samples but I still don't get it. Do you guys have any simple code that I can understand?

I haven't started the code yet since I don't know how to start it. All I know is that, it is about `mouseDragged` or `MouseMotionListener`.

Comment: Just post the image link, then I can include it in your post

Comment: This is what my jframe looks like. @msrd0
https://www.dropbox.com/lightbox/home

Comment: The link you posted referrs to my home directory in dropbox. Please click left on the share symbol and then post the link given you by dropbox.

Comment: Oh wait. I'm sorry. Here.. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbud87n9losvavg/drag.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Okay I added the image. Did you found the `JFrame.setLocation` method?

Comment: Gee thanks. 
Not yet. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24476755/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following:

```
public class DragFrame extends JFrame {

  int mpX, mpY;

  public DragFrame() {

    addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
          mpX = e.getX();
          mpY = e.getY();
        }
    } );

    addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ) {
          setLocation(
              getLocation().x + e.getX() - mpX,
              getLocation().y + e.getY() - mpY );
        }
    } );
  }
}
```

Thanks to *@peeskillet* for giving the crucial link to [Drag and Resize undecorated JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24476755/1744774) with the inspiration to save the mouse position on `mousePressed(...)`.

Comment: I tried that. Look what happened.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hivv6l331vwpxnp/DragFrame.xesc?dl=0

Comment: @Robert Very creative way of communication! :-) That's the same effect as I mentioned above. With a smaller JFrame here [setBounds( 100, 100, 400, 300 )] but with the window being drawn on two different places in quick succession, seeming as two windows then.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess that you'll need to overwrite the `MoseMotionListener.mouseDragged` method was correct. Then, you need to call [`JFrame.setLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocation-int-int-) to move your `JFrame`, like this:

```
class FrameMoveListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    private Point lastPos;
    private Frame frame;

    public FrameMoveListener (Frame f)
    {
        frame = f; // mustn't be null
    }

    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent evt)
    {
        if (lastPos != null)
        {
            int x = lastPos.x - evt.getX();
            int y = lastPos.y - evt.getY();
            f.setLocation(f.getLocationOnScreen().x + x,
                          f.getLocationOnScreen().y + y);
        }
        lastPos = new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Would you elaborate it more? Thanks

Comment: What should I do with the f?

Comment: @Robert `yourFrame.addMouseMotionListener( new FrameMoveListener( yourFrame ) );`

Comment: @Robert Do what _Gerold Broser_ said to "connect" your `FrameMoveListener` to your frame. If you are not sure that `f` never gets `null`, you should add `if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();` to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

use this method is simple and perfec

final Component obj - your JFrame, JLabel, any Component
final boolean info - if you want display the position when release de left click

```
public static void Move(final Component obj,final boolean info) {

        MouseInputAdapter d=new MouseInputAdapter() {int x,X,y,Y;
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){x=e.getXOnScreen();X=obj.getLocation().x;y=e.getYOnScreen();Y=obj.getLocation().y;}}
        @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){obj.setLocation(X+(e.getXOnScreen()-x), Y+(e.getYOnScreen()-y));}}
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){if(info && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){System.err.println(obj.toString().substring(0,obj.toString().indexOf("["))+" ("+obj.getLocation().x+","+obj.getLocation().y+")");}}};
        obj.addMouseListener(d);obj.addMouseMotionListener(d);
    }
```

this is the format code:

```
public static void Mover(final Component obj, final boolean info) {

        MouseInputAdapter d = new MouseInputAdapter() {
            int x, X, y, Y;

            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    x = e.getXOnScreen();
                    X = obj.getLocation().x;
                    y = e.getYOnScreen();
                    Y = obj.getLocation().y;
                }
            }
            @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    obj.setLocation(X + (e.getXOnScreen() - x), Y + (e.getYOnScreen() - y));
                }
            }
            @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (info && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    System.err.println(obj.toString().substring(0, obj.toString().indexOf("[")) + " (" + obj.getLocation().x + "," + obj.getLocation().y + ")");
                }
            }
        };
        obj.addMouseListener(d);
        obj.addMouseMotionListener(d);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. :D It works! But this is for the objects like button, text, bg, etc. How will I move the whole frame?

Comment: @Robert A [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) is a Component, too. Once you have other components on your Frame/ContentPane see [How to Use Root Panes, The glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html): _"The glass pane is useful when you want to be able to catch events [...] over an area that already contains one or more components."_

Comment: exact with this method you can move all kind of Components, I use this always to edit the position of my elements and for custom JFrames