# How to make the Jframe move when I click and drag it using my mouse

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been trying to accomplish how to move the jframe when I drag it using the mouse. But I couldn't find a solution to it.

I have tried to implement listeners on the Jframe but it doesn't work the way I have intended it to.

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setSize(500,500);
jframe.setLocation(400, 100);
jframe.setVisible(true);

jframe.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
   });
```

Comment: I don't understand. `JFrame` is draggable by default. Just place the mouse pointer in the `JFrame` title bar and drag the mouse. Does your `JFrame` not have a title bar? Do you want to drag the `JFrame` in a different way other than placing the mouse in the title bar? What platform are you on? Are you on Windows? Or Linux? Or Mac? Something else?

Comment: The frame doesn't have a title bar as I have disabled it. I need to be able to move the frame when I drag it using the mouse pointer.

Comment: [Drag and Resize undecorated JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476496/drag-and-resize-undecorated-jframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MouseMotionListener. Get the position of the mouse when you move the mouse using mouseMoved event method and use it with the drag event to position the frame accordingly. :

```
jframe.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    xDrag = e.getX();
    yDrag = e.getY();

    JFrame sFrame = (JFrame) e.getSource();
    sFrame.setLocation(sFrame.getLocation().x+xDrag-xPress, 
    sFrame.getLocation().y+yDrag-yPress);
 }

 @Override
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
     xPress = e.getX();
     yPress = e.getY();
  }
});
```

Declare the variables xDrag, yDrag, xPress, yPress in your class. I hope this helps.